# Downloading all PDFs corresponding to a list of references

Tags: download-manager, scraping, research

I am looking for a program, browser extension or website is that can download all PDFs corresponding to a list of references.

Example:

Given the input:

> 1. Paoloni JA, Appleyard RC, Nelson J, Murrell GA. Topical nitric oxide application in the treatment of chronic extensor tendinosis at
>      the elbow: a randomized, double-blinded, placebo- controlled clinical
>      trial. Am J Sports Med. 2003;31(6):915–20.
> 2. Paoloni JA, Murrell GA, Burch RM, Ang RY. Randomised, double-blind. placebo-controlled clinical trial of a new topical glyceryl trinitrate
>      patch for chronic lateral epicondylosis. Br J Sports Med.
>      2009;43(4):299–302.
> 3. Bokhari AR, Murrell GA. The role of nitric oxide in tendon healing. J Shoulder Elbow Surg. 2012;21(2):238–44.
> 4. McCallum SD, Paoloni JA, Murrell GA. Five-year prospective comparison study of topical glyceryl trinitrate treatment of chronic
>      lateral epicondylosis at the elbow. Br J Sports Med.
>      2011;45(5):416–20.

the output should be 4 PDFs, each one corresponding to one reference.

Any license, OS and price is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to take a look at [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com) which has a citations manager plug in for various tool chains but to be able to add the papers to your library and then to be able to download the cited papers you will need to be subscribed to the journal(s) or libraries in question.  Once you are you can add the cited papers to your library and download, *including bulk downloads*, to various devices.

Mendeley:

- has free and paid features
- has Desktop Apps for Windows, OS-X & Linux
- has Web interface
- has Browser Plug In
- Allows pdf viewing, searching & annotation
- Handles 1000s of citation styles

Comment: Does Mendeley also has a sci-hub.(cc) integration for those who cannot access articles behind a paywall?

Comment: @andselisk I very much doubt that but I will have to see. If that exists, our lives will be simplified beyond recognition . I swear, citation management often takes more time than the rest of the paper.

Comment: Of interest: http://incubator.rockefeller.edu/skirting-around-paywalls-how-scientists-quickly-get-the-articles-they-need/ (I do __not__ recommend these processes)!